# Is there a non-ulimit heap memory limit in recent libc or linux kernel?

Tags: linux

```
Linux mint64 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The following program fails on my just-installed Linux Mint 15 on the above-captioned 64-bit system. It's running in a VM with 4GB of 'physical' memory. Works fine on my Mac, and on

```
Linux hercules 3.2.0-24-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 21 16:52:17 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ulimit asserts that no limits are in force. strace shows an mmap failure:

```
mmap(NULL, 4836167680, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

Further experimentation shows that turning on overcommit makes it 'work'.

The `free` command shows:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3993228    3098188     895040          0     137680    2255620
-/+ buffers/cache:     704888    3288340
Swap:      1046524          0    1046524
```

Is there some new control mechanism in the picture? Why does swap matter if there's plenty of (?) physical memory on hand?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void *m = malloc(4836032512);
  if (m == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate ~4MB of memory with malloc?\n");
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It now seems obvious that if you ask for 4gb of memory, you better have more than 4gb of memory, and the other systems I tried it on have, well, more than 4gb of memory.

Comment: How much virtual memory do you have?  Use the free command to show it.  Swap contributes to virtual memory.

Comment: Free shows 851 free megabytes, so what's so hard about allocating 4?

Comment: No, not precisely. But a lot closer to 4 than 800.

Comment: No, it's 4GB and change.

Comment: Oh, gah. what was I thinking? OK, well, that would explain a desire for overcommit. I guess I have a different problem, which is how C++ came up with a desire for this much memory in the first place. Let me think about what do to with this quesiton.